# Time zone list. How to get it for particular device?

Tags: android, timezone

I need to fill up my Spinner with Time zones EXACTLY like it filled in settings -> date&time -> select time zone menu. If I use just

```
TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```

I get complitly different view. I.e. in settings menu it looks like:

```
Midway Island
Hawaii
Alaska
...
```

in my spinner I get

```
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
....
```

Answer (score 2):

In Android, Settings app translates from the ids to common names. you can find the xml that is used for translation is here

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com$java$ext@com.google.android$android-apps@4.0.4_r1.2@packages$apps$Settings$res$xml$timezones.xml

. 
So you will also have to translate it to common names programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the ids, you need to use `TimeZone.getTimeZone(id).getDisplayName()` in order to see the names in the format used in the Android settings. Be aware though that some of the ids result in the same display name so you'll need to filter items that have the same display name.